# Can the "images" folder be named something else in lightbox?

Tags: lightbox2

I am using Lokesh Dhakar's Lightbox on my page.  I renamed the css and js folders to be _css and _js on my server and all works except I also renamed the "img" folder to be "_img", and the image icons (close, loading, prev and next) don't work.  Are you not able to have this folder be named something other than "image" or "img"?  Thanks.

Comment: Did you update all references to the 'img' folder to be '_img'?  For example in the CSS files and JS files?

Comment: No, but that would help.  And it did.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly that, changed the name. Just make sure in CSS and JS and you have the correct links to the new folder.